# hp procurve 2510-48 vlan port access

Tags: networking

I have a question I have two hp procurve 2510-48 switches and I have two companies sharing a network and I want to separate them by giving them their own VLAN. However they share a phone system so I want to grant ports access to phone system VLAN. How can I go about granting ports the ability to talk to another VLAN assuming they are on a sub net that can talk to each other?

Comment: Why not separate the phone system onto a third VLAN?

Comment: It is on a 3rd vlan.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use 802.11q vlans (tagging). This allows ports to belong to more than one vlan. So you will have a set of ports that only belong to the vlan for company A, a set of ports that only belong to the vlan for company B, and a set of ports that are members of both vlans, where the phone system equipment is connected.

Comment: I have setup the vlans so phone system is on the main vlan, company A is on another and company B on the 3rd vlan. This however allows company A and B able to ping one another. Now I will need to setup DHCP for company A and B. If A and B are able to ping one another wont this interfere with proper DHCP leasing?